# how to debug program without entering Android system files such as activity.class

Tags: java, android

I am debugging a program and I am pressing F6 to step through the code. But it actually takes me to android system files such as activity.class and looper.class. I have no need to be taken here.. I just want to debug the code which the programmer wrote. Is there a way stop this ? I am on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it for debugging Android projects, but the "Use Step Filters" function can be configured to automatically pass/ignore classes in certain packages when performing step-by-step debugging.

See Eclipse help for details: [Use Step Filters](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could set multiple brake-points on the lines that you want to debug, and go from one to anoter with F7.